How to use symbolic regression from the gramEval package in R?
I'm trying to run a symbolic regression using the gramEval package in R. I'm running a test on the IRIS data and it seems to be working. However, when I use other data with many variables and class imbalance, it seems that there is something wrong in the implementation. Could you please tell me if, for this example, the implementation is correct?
I think there may be an implementation error in  SymRegFitFunc function or ruleDef.
    `# Load the required libraries
#### Setup ###
source("_Setup.R")
library(magrittr)
library(gramEvol)

kFolds = 10L
resultados <- list()
resultados$Desempenhos <- tibble()

# Load the iris dataset
data(iris)

dadosModelo <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = as.factor(Species) %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  mutate(Species = ifelse(test = Species == 1, yes = 0,1)) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_c("x", .x), -Species) %>% 
  select(y = Species, everything()) %>% 
  as_tibble()


nVars = ncol(dadosModelo) - 1
nomeBase <- "Iris"

#### Split dataset  ####
resultados$DivisaoDados[[nomeBase]] <- SplitDataset(
  dados = dadosModelo,
  kFolds = kFolds, 
  porcaoTreinoKS = 0.9, 
  arquivoCache = NULL,  
  buscarCache = FALSE
)

linhasTreinoTeste = resultados$DivisaoDados[[nomeBase]]


for (fold in 1:kFolds) {
  
  Msg(
    bold("Base de Dados: "), 
    bold(yellow(nomeBase)),
    " ___ ",
    "/",
    "\n \n",
    bold(blue("Fold: ")),
    bold(blue(fold)),
    "/",
    bold(kFolds)
  )
  
  # Extracts training and testing data from folds
  dadosTreinoCV <- dadosModelo[linhasTreinoTeste$LinhasTreinoTesteFolds$LinhasTreino[[fold]] %>% unlist(), ]
  dadosTesteCV <- dadosModelo[linhasTreinoTeste$LinhasTreinoTesteFolds$LinhasTeste[[fold]] %>% unlist(), ]
  
  #### Symbolic Regression ####
  # Training data
  x_train <- dadosTreinoCV[, 2:nVars]
  y_train <- dadosTreinoCV$y
  
  # Testing data
  x_test <- dadosTesteCV[, 2:nVars]
  y_test <- dadosTesteCV$y
  
  # Generate the list of variables dynamically
  var_names <- colnames(x_train)
  
  # Create the grammar rules for symbolic regression
  var_rule <- do.call(grule, lapply(var_names, as.name))
  
  ruleDef <- list(
    expr = grule(op(expr, expr), func(expr), var),
    func = grule(sin, cos, sqrt, log, exp), # grule(sin, cos, log, exp),
    op = grule('+', '-', '*', '/'),
    var = var_rule
  )
  
  # Create grammar from defined rules
  grammarDef <- CreateGrammar(ruleDef)
  
  # Tuning function 
  SymRegFitFunc <- function(expr) {
    env <- as.list(x_train)
    result <- try(eval(expr, envir = env), silent = TRUE)
    
    if (inherits(result, "try-error") || is.language(result) || length(result) != length(y_train)) {
      return(Inf)  # Usar Inf para indicar um ajuste ruim
    } else {
      
      # Converter previsões contínuas para valores discretos (categorias)
      predicted_classes <- ifelse(result < 0.5, 0, 1)
      # predicted_classes <- ifelse(result < 2, 0, 1)
      
      # Calcular a matriz de confusão
      confusion_matrix <- table(predicted_classes, y_train)
      
      
      # Verdadeiros positivos
      VP <- ifelse(
        test = ("1" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "1" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
        yes = confusion_matrix["1", "1"],
        no = 0 
      ) 
      
      # Verdadeiros negativos
      VN <- ifelse(
        test = ("0" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "0" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
        yes = confusion_matrix["0", "0"],
        no = 0 
      ) 
      
      # Falsos positivos
      FP <- ifelse(
        test = ("1" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "0" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
        yes = confusion_matrix["0", "1"],
        no = 0  
      ) 
      
      # Falsos negativos
      FN <- ifelse(
        test = ("0" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "1" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
        yes = confusion_matrix["1", "0"],
        no = 0
      ) 
      
      # Calcular a acurácia
      sensitivity <- VP/(VP + FN)
      specificity <- VN/(VN + FP)
      # accuracy <- (VP + VN) / (VP + VN + FP + FN)
      accuracy <- sum((predicted_classes == y_train) %>% as.numeric())/ length(y_train) # numero de previsoes corretas / nº total de previsoes
      
      if(is.nan(accuracy) || is.na(accuracy)){
        accuracy <- 0
      }
      
      return(1-accuracy)  # Retornar o negativo da acurácia, pois queremos maximizar
    }
  }
  
  # Carry out grammatical evolution
  ge <- GrammaticalEvolution(
    grammarDef,
    SymRegFitFunc,
    terminationCost = 0.1,
    iterations = 2500,
    max.depth = 5
  )
  
  # Show results
  cat("Grammatical Evolution Search Results:\n")
  cat("  No. Generations: ", ge$generation, "\n")
  cat("  Best Expression: ", deparse(ge$best$expressions[[1]]), "\n")
  cat("  Best Cost: ", ge$best$cost, "\n")
  
  # Evaluate model performance
  env <- as.list(x_test)
  predictions <- try(eval(ge$best$expressions[[1]], envir = env), silent = TRUE)
  
  # Convert continuous forecasts to discrete values ​​(categories)
  predicted_classes <- ifelse(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)
  # Calculate the confusion matrix
  confusion_matrix <- table(predicted_classes, y_test)
  
  # True positives
  VP <- ifelse(
    test = ("1" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "1" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
    yes = confusion_matrix["1", "1"],
    no = 0 
  ) 
  
  # True negatives
  VN <- ifelse(
    test = ("0" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "0" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
    yes = confusion_matrix["0", "0"],
    no = 0 
  ) 
  
  # False positives
  FP <- ifelse(
    test = ("1" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "0" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
    yes = confusion_matrix["0", "1"],
    no = 0  
  ) 
  
  # False negatives
  FN <- ifelse(
    test = ("0" %in% colnames(confusion_matrix) && "1" %in% rownames(confusion_matrix)),
    yes = confusion_matrix["1", "0"],
    no = 0
  ) 
  
  # Calculate accuracy
  sensitivity <- VP/(VP + FN)
  specificity <- VN/(VN + FP)
  # accuracy <- (VP + VN) / (VP + VN + FP + FN)
  
  accuracy <- sum((predicted_classes == y_test) %>% as.numeric())/ length(y_test) # numero de previsoes corretas / nº total de previsoes
  
  
  cat("Accuracy: ", accuracy, "\n")
  cat("Sensitivity: ", sensitivity, "\n")
  cat("Specificity: ", specificity, "\n")
  
  desempenhos <- tibble(
    BaseDados = nomeBase,
    Fold = fold,
    Acc = accuracy,
    Sens = sensitivity, # com valores NaN
    Spec = specificity, # com valores NaN
  )
  
  resultados$Desempenhos <- resultados$Desempenhos %>% 
    bind_rows(desempenhos)
}`


